# Use of 'Happiest' in wishing birthday?

Tags: word-usage, comparatives

Recently, I have seen some people writing:

'Happiest birthday, John'

What exactly does this mean? *Happiest* implies a comparison with something, but the phrase is usually used without any context that would make it clear what the basis of the comparison is.

If the aim is merely to provide emphasis, wouldn't 'A very happy birthday, John' be better?

Is *happiest* an apt term to use in expressing birthday wishes?

Comment: Where did you see this? In what context? Why do you think it is not grammatically correct? If *Happy* is fine, why would *Happier* and *Happiest* not be?

Comment: I have seen people wishing happiest birthday instead of happy birthday in messages. What I know is that happier and happiest are used when we compare. But, they are saying happiest without any comparison.

Comment: It is a matter of opinion I am afraid. But if you read this article [_Is It Correct to Say “Happiest of Birthdays”?_](https://grammarhow.com/happiest-of-birtdays-correct/), you may be able to form an opinion of your own. On this site though, we do not discuss opinions, but facts.

Comment: The question is not about the **grammatical** correctness of the phrase (as suggested by Mr. Leach, *happiest* can't be any less correct, grammatically, than *happy*), but about its **meaning**. It has, therefore, been edited to remove references to grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Happy birthday* is not 'grammatically correct' as a sentence; it's a conventional way of saying *I wish you a happy birthday.* So *Happiest birthday* could mean *I wish you the happiest possible birthday.*

Comment: "Safe travels!" and "Better luck next time!" come to mind.

Comment: I don’t think “grammatically correct as a sentence” matters here. It’s a common and unremarkable utterance that is perfectly grammatical as an utterance. It need not be a sentence *per se* to be grammatical. It is not intended to have a subject and a finite verb because those elements are predictably skipped under conversational deletion. ***(I hope you have)** better luck next time* might be the clause structure inferred here.

Comment: @tchrist - That's why I put the expression in inverted commas - grammatical correctness had been mentioned in earlier comments.